# PHP : Login with out parameter of stored procedure

Tags: php, stored-procedures, pdo

I've been trying to create a login page using pdo with out parameter of stored procedure.

The request handling

```
  if (isset($_POST['login'])){
    $UserId = $_POST['UserId'];
    $UserPwd = $_POST['UserPwd'];
```

Here is my code

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM UserLogin @varUserId as UserId, @varUserPwd as UserPwd VALUES (?,?)"); 
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $UserId, $UserPwd,PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 4000);
$stmt->execute();
```

Here is the error that I get

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on
>   boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:22 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 22

Which refering to this code line

```
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $UserId, $UserPwd,PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 4000);
```

HTML of the login form

```
<html>
    <head><title>Login</title></head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" name="login">
            <input type="text" name="UserId">
            <input type="text" name="UserPwd">
            <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please help me.

Comment: Your code is just a bizarre mix of technologies and peculiar fantasies. Start from telling us what is that "stored procedure" you're talking about and why the idea to use it

Comment: _Your code is just a bizarre mix of technologies and peculiar fantasies_ Please tell me more. I'm a new learner. I'm trying to call variables from the stored procedure to be use in a login. I've succesfully implemented the login with phpmyadmin database and now i'm trying with stored procedure. @YourCommonSense

Answer (score -1):

change to

```
$sql  = 'SELECT * FROM UserLogin where UserId = ? and UserPwd = ?';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$UserId, $UserPwd]);
$count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```